# Is this SQLite Update query correct?

Tags: sqlite

```
String query = "UPDATE CONTACT SET NAME ='" + 
contact.getName()"',phoneNO='" + 
contact.getContactNumber() + 
"' WHERE ID = "+contact.getId();
```

Comment: What is contact?  String concatenation is bad for sql queries - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Please format your post !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   "UPDATE CONTACT SET NAME ='" + 
   contact.getName() +
    "',phoneNO='" + 
   contact.getContactNumber() + 
   "' WHERE ID = " +
   contact.getId();
```

You are missing a "+" after the getName().  But this whole approach is risky because the name and other parameters could contain quotes or other characters that could cause the statement to be parsed incorrectly (SQL injection).

It is safer to embed the query string with named parameters instead.

Like

```
   "UPDATE CONTACT SET NAME = @name, phoneNO - @phone WHERE ID = @ID"
```

Then you define the values for @name, @phone, and @ID when you execute.  This is much safer.  The exact details of how you do that depends on the database you are using and the API